# Failed to query available provider packages issue

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

> Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching ">= 2.49.0, >= 3.0.0, ~> 3.37, >= 3.40.0, >= 3.63.0, >= 4.0.0, >= 4.7.0"...

> Error: Failed to query available provider packages
> Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws: no available releases match the given constraints >= 2.49.0, >= 3.0.0, ~> 3.37, >= 3.40.0, >= 3.63.0, >= 4.0.0, >= 4.7.0

main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.14"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.37"
    }
  }
}
```

What could be the reason of this issue?

Comment: I'm guessing you are using modules and they have their own `required_providers` blocks defined?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: You can run the command `terraform providers` to see specifically which module depends on which range of versions. You'll need to select your modules and module versions so that they all have at least one version of the provider in common that they are compatible with.

Comment: In particular, `~> 3.37` and `>= 4.0.0` are incompatible with one another, because the first one is a shorthand for `>= 3.37.0, < 4.0.0` and so there can be no version that satisfies both constraints.

Comment: @MartinAtkins, ~> allows only the rightmost version component to increment: ~> 1.0.4 will allow installation of 1.0.5 and 1.0.10 but not 1.1.0